# Revealing MySQL row ID in source code: okay or bad?

Tags: jquery, mysql

There are a few jQuery plugins (jqgrid, DataTables, etc.) for displaying data in a html table with advanced features. The ones that have a live editing ability either store the mysql row id in the table itself (and make it uneditable), or as something like a row id in the source.

I have also read that revealing anything about your database design is a bad idea.

Is revealing a mysql row id in source code or the table itself a big deal? Does it just depend on the sensitivity of the data?

Would it be better to have a hash table in the javascript that matches an html table row id with a mysql row id?

Comment: It's generally verboten to expose the primary key to users - they can become dependent on it, making changing away (if/when necessary) difficult.  It's also a security issue - SQL injection can do a lot more damage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are depending on the "[obscurity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security_through_obscurity)" of your data model to protect you against problems like [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection), you will be sorely disappointed.  Also, if you are not sanity checking values that the user is providing (a rowid to update, for instance), you will have gaping holes in your application.  This is independent of what you use to identify data in your application.  The primary key, in and of itself, is not generally sensitive data.

In short, using the row id to identify data coming from your user through your app is not a problem providing you are sanity checking user input like you need to do anyway.  As a note of caution, you can run into some problems if you are displaying the ids in the URL as users tend to bookmark pages in the most strange places.  It doesn't sound like you're wanting to do that though.

See [Should I obscure primary key values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1895685/should-i-obscure-primary-key-values) for a related discussion.

Comment: I do try and sanitize all data (I use mysql real escape string).

Also, the id wouldn't be in the URL, it would just be an html id for a row. So the bookmark issue isn't the case.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

As you mentioned it is depending on the sensitivity of the data. However I would like to explain you the way I did for this kind of situation. May be it will help you.

I added the ID of database table row as the HTML table row ID. When someone edit that. I checked several things once I get the request.

1. Is this user is authenticated
2. Does this user has privilege to edit a row of this module
3. Is this selected row can be edited by this user.

You can combine 2 and 3 steps together as well. If you want more security or auditing you can keep a log as well.

If you need you can encode the ID and set it as row ID. When you get the edit request you can decode it and get.